# Is it possible to roll Stealth versus multiple targets when one or more can see you?

Tags: dnd-4e, stealth

Is it possible to roll `Stealth` versus multiple targets when one or more can see you?

So for example, if the character moves into the corridor, where the majority of the monsters can no longer see her, but one monster still has a line of sight ... can the character roll `Stealth`?

And if she can, who is she hidden from ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Yes**

To be hidden, you must meet the following requirements:

- Have total concealment/superior cover from at least one foe (being out of line of sight is included in these: it's superior cover, essentially).
- Make a Stealth check and beat the passive perception of your foe.

It is absolutely possible to be hidden from certain foes and not from others. You gain combat advantage against any foe you are hidden from.

Reference Stealth on p. 152 of RC or the Stealth entry in DDI. Also: obligatory link to [Rules of Hidden Club](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/2739081), which is a thorough explanation of how exactly Stealth works in D&D 4e.

Comment: I've wondered about this before, too.  If you're hidden from several enemies, can't the one who can see you can simply turn to the others and tell them where you are?  "Hey, she's crouched behind that crate!"  The others can't see you, but they know where you are.  That doesn't seem the same as being "hidden." How would that affect combat advantage?

Comment: @Lechlerfan in 4e "being hidden" and "presence unknown" are totally different. Outside of very exceptional circumstances all creatures always know where all other creatures are, so my character does not need your character to tell me that someone is hiding behind the curtain / standing invisible in front of me / wherever. I already know that. The advantage that their hidden-ness provides is that they can strike at me with combat advantage.

Comment: @SimonWithers hidden is actually an exception to this rule (the only exception in fact). However, if even one foe can see you/beats your stealth check, your position is effectively known as pointed out, any foe could relay your position.

Comment: As explained in the hidden club link, being Hidden is a huge advantage even if all the enemies know where you are, because you have all the benefits of being invisible (no OAs against you, any melee or ranged attack is at -5 due to total concealment, CA on attacks).

Answer (score -2):

Enemies would have roll against intelligence to effectively coordinate themselves with some penalty for separation - whether it be detecting hidden PC or best PC to attack by which enemy. If low intelligence, it would like there is a guy over there, where? and then the PC attacks them so its all pointless.

Comment: Can you unpack how you got to this conclusion and how this impacts rolling stealth against multiple targets?

Comment: Sounds like he is just throwing out a house rule via dm fiat for the situation.